# Can I add Vertical Tab on a Node Edit Page in admin

Tags: nodes, forms

I am hoping to add a custom Vertical Tab in node edit page. Is it possible?

As an example, someone did it like this:-
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with hook_form_alter. Similar example can be found in the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module. Take a look at [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/vertical_tabs_example!vertical_tabs_example.module/function/vertical_tabs_example_form_alter/7) after you are done with your form tabs, add a custom submit handler like `$form[#submit][] = 'my_custom_submit';` and then save the data in submit handler using `variable_set()` method like this:

```
variable_set('MYMODULE_' . $form_state['values']['your_value'] . '_special_option', $values);
```

**Note**: put it in `template.php` or in a custom module.

Comment: Thanks Shabir ... should I put it in template.php?

Comment: Yes. or in custom module

Comment: Please check my edits I just applied, to ensure I didn't introduce anything you didn't want. Maybe you also want to reword the "**Note**" part I added somehow (eg: remove the "note"-word itself?). If anything else fails: just rollback

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to everyone now. I am sorry for my poor english ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module to add groups and 1 of the options is vertical tabs:

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group